# Combining groupby and apply in multiIndex DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working with a multiIndex DataFrame and want to do some groupby / apply() operations. I am struggling with how to combine groupby and apply.

I would like to extract the values of two indices of my DataFrame and compare those values in an apply function.

For those occurrences where the apply function is true, I would like to do a groupby / sum over the values of my DataFrame.

Is there a good way to do this without using for loops?

---

```
 # Index specifier
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'],
     ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
     ['A', 'B', 'C']],
    names=['SimulationStart', 'ProjectionPeriod', 'Group']
)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60,1), index= ix, columns=['Input'])

# Calculate sum over all projection periods for each simulation/group
all_periods = df.groupby(level=['SimulationStart', 'Group']).sum()

# This part of the code is not working yet
# is there a way to extract data from the indices of the DataFrame?
# Calculate sum over all projection periods for each simulation/group;
# where projection period is a maximum of one year in the future
one_year_ahead = df.groupby(level=['SimulationStart', 'Group']) \
                   .apply(lambda x: x['ProjectionPeriod'] - \
                                    x['SimulationStart'] <= 1).sum()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could calculate the difference, `ProjectionPeriod - SimulationStart`, *before* performing the `groupby/sum` operation.

```
get_values = df.index.get_level_values
mask = (get_values('ProjectionPeriod') - get_values('SimulationStart')) <= 1
one_year_ahead = df.loc[mask].groupby(level=['SimulationStart', 'Group']).sum()
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018], 
     [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020], ['A', 'B', 'C']],
    names=['SimulationStart', 'ProjectionPeriod', 'Group'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60,1), index= ix, columns=['Input'])

get_values = df.index.get_level_values
mask = (get_values('ProjectionPeriod') - get_values('SimulationStart')) <= 1
one_year_ahead = df.loc[mask].groupby(level=['SimulationStart', 'Group']).sum()
print(one_year_ahead)
```

yields

```
                          Input
SimulationStart Group          
2015            A      0.821851
                B     -0.643342
                C     -0.140112
2016            A      0.384885
                B     -0.252186
                C     -1.057493
2017            A     -1.055933
                B      1.096221
                C     -4.150002
2018            A      0.584859
                B     -4.062078
                C      1.225105
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This is extremely helpful. My code doesn't quite work yet because the periods in the indices are actually in string format.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it.

```
df.reset_index().query('ProjectionPeriod - SimulationStart == 1') \
    .groupby(['SimulationStart', 'Group']).Input.sum()

SimulationStart  Group
2015             A        1.100246
                 B       -0.605710
                 C        1.366465
2016             A        0.359406
                 B       -2.077444
                 C       -0.004356
2017             A        0.604497
                 B       -0.362941
                 C        0.103945
2018             A       -0.861976
                 B       -0.737274
                 C        0.237512
Name: Input, dtype: float64
```

---

Because you have unique values in the `Group` column, this also works but I don't believe its what you want.

```
df.reset_index().query('ProjectionPeriod - SimulationStart == 1') \
    [['SimulationStart', 'Group', 'Input']]
```

[image]